# Has anybody earned $0.25+ from each of a captcha (on your website) passing?

Tags: advertising, payments, spam, spam-prevention, captcha

I am a real dummy in [web monetizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website_monetization) schemes.

[ 1 ] informs that a captcha vendor:

- "charges a fee of about 25 cents to 50 cents for each form that is filled out using a Type-In ad [captcha]...  the company splits its fees 50-50 with the websites where the ads are placed"

There is a dozen of other similar captchas promoted as advertising platforms.

Honestly, I cannot imagine that someone (in its proper senses) pasy that much money for just one captcha passed.
And how to understand these claims?

Has any of webmasters (sysadmins) got those 0.25 USD per each captcha (deployed on his/her website)  passing?

Is it scam?

What do I miss?

**Update:**
Sorry, I cleaned and, as I hope, cleared my original question: 
Had anybody received those 50% from 50c per each captcha passing deployed on his website?

This approach looks weird to me since those captchas aren't even minimally protected against automatic OCR passing by a bot. They are also completely transparent to laundry and redirection attacks, i.e. their re-transferring by bots to (again automatically, through offered APIs) human solver sweatshops cracking them at 1 USD per 1000 solutions.

Cited:
[ 1 ]
Jennifer Valentino-DeVries
"An Online Ad That’s Tough to Ignore"
WallStreet Journal Blog
SEPTEMBER 20, 2010
http://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2010/09/20/an-online-ad-thats-tough-to-ignore/

Comment: Large brands like IE, Toyota, are focused on engagement these days on the web. They are less worried about a click-through and just want to make sure readers are paying attention to the ad, perhaps watching an embedded video, etc. I am sure they are looking at this as an engagement and .25-.50 is actually cheap as far as an engagement goes.

Comment: This is actually really smart advertising. I'd be willing to pay 50c to advertise my company in this way (if I felt it wasn't an ethical grey area)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt they're getting quite the rates quoted in the article, but it doesn't look like a scam. Advertisers genuinely will pay more for something that improves engagement with and recall of the ad.

Answer (score 1):

figure you take the beta, use IE 9, and then Bing for search instead of google.  The 25 cents comes back 100 fold.

MSFT is not dumb.  They have done their market research and have deep pockets to buy a market.